# How to get formatted date into p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar, date-format

I am developing a JSF and primefaces application. In my `some.xhtml` file where I put `p: calendar` tag and I want to set its default value as current date (format e.g:`01-09-2014`). I have written `private Date startDate;` in backing bean.

```xml
<p:calendar value="#{bean.startDate}">
```

When I don't write below code and just assign
`private Date startDate = Calendar.getInstance();` it gives me default value(`MON Sep 1 00:00:00 EST 2014`) but not in proper format (`01-09-2014`) which I really want. So my question is that how to set date in custom format (`01-09-2014`) and assign it to `Date` object `private Date startDate = this.defaultDate();` (see below:) to get default value in clientside
with this(`01-09-2014`) format.

I am using jdk 1.7.

```
private Date startDate = this.defaultDate();
private Date defaultDate() {
    Date defaultDate = null;
    try {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        defaultDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return defaultDate;
}
```

Comment: good demo. Now what???

Comment: What u want from here? Do you  get any error or ?

Comment: @amitbhardwaj:- Please go through the code. Although I agree that its difficult to find but the question and problem is in the code and explained there

Answer (score -1):

You are parsing the date correctly (kind of, see below) with the `DateFormatter` but not formatting it again for display:-

```
 sdf.format(defaultDate);
```

That is to say, when you output it:-

```
 System.out.println(sdf.format(defaultDate));
```

A `Date` object only holds an actual date, not information on how it should be formatted or which pieces of information contained in the `Date` to display (seconds, minutes, hours, day of week, day of month, month, year).  Hence the use of `DateFormatter` to select only the parts you wish to display, in the order you wish to display them.

**Additionally**

When you are originally getting the date:-

```
defaultDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

You are getting a `Date` object (with `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`), converting it to a `String` using your `DateFormatter` (with `sdf.format()`) then using your `DateFormatter` to convert it back to a `Date` (with `sdf.parse()`) when you could just do:-

```
Date defaultDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String displayDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

this will give you formatted date in the format `dd-MM-yyyy` as string

Comment: This doesn't work.  There is no overloaded `parse()` which accepts a `Date` object